# C# to C++ code (using CLI) giving error

Tags: c#, c++

Sorry for the terribly vague name, I wasn't quite sure how to be more specific.

I'm using a C# package in C++, the C++ code is reporting an error but I'm unsure why.

The C# code:

```
subwindowKit.SetBackground(Subwindow.Background.Transparent);
```

The C++ code:

```
subwindowKit->SetBackground(Csharppackage::Subwindow.Background.Transparent);
```

Which is giving the error "Type name is not allowed" (while referring to "Csharppackage::Subwindow").

Similar syntax has worked earlier, but I'm not sure why it isn't here.

Comment: Try `HPS::Subwindow::Background::Transparent` instead. However it is hard to tell without proper class definitions of `HPS::Subwindow`

Comment: Ah, you hero Erbureth. That worked perfectly. If you want to put that as an answer I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.` operator in C++ can be used only on instances of class. Static members are referred by `::` operator

Therefore you should try `HPS::Subwindow::Background::Transparent` instead